# !4.04 still having an amd radeon r9 380. are their drivers still compatible with the latest ubuntu version?

Tags: 14.04, updates, radeon, amd-graphics

I am a new linux users that got his pc about a year ago. I still have my good and old AMD Radeon R9 380. The thing is that i couldn't upgrade my Ubuntu to a newer version (lets say... 16.04) because that version didn't have the drivers required for the card to work properly. I want to know if the newer versions of Ubuntu have any form of compatibility with my graphics card. And if yes, how do i upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely caused by a kernel change. You can try the following:

1. Add the repository of the version you want to upgrade to.
2. Update `apt`
3. Install the new kernel and headers. `dpkg` should recompile the video driver for the new kernel.
4. Be sure to update GRUB, then reboot
5. If the above succeeded, do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

Comment: 1.- what do i do to add the repository? 2.- sudo apt-update no? 3.- i just write dpkg to install it? 4.- how?

Comment: edit the /etc/apt/sources.list. change the first line that is uncommented. it will look someting like this: deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main. yours of course will say ubuntu instead of debian. stable is the newest stable version. you can replace it with the nick if the version you want ie. trusty, utopia, xenial etc NOTE: root privilages is needed to edit